# Fastest way to copy over a postgres database to BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, devops, database-administration

**Problem statement**: It is necessary to copy over a 100GB database from a `GCP Postgres DB` into `GCP BigQuery` located in the same region/availability zone. Ideally, I'd like to be able to make a full copy every 15-20 minutes.

**Attempt at the solution**:

1. Using Airbyte --> take several hours which is waaaaay too slow.
2. Using pg_dump --> Also did quiet make the mark.

**Question**: What other things can I try ? What other tools are available which will enable me to do this ? I think the issue here is the network transfer speed ... I seem to be somehow getting about 2Mb/s or similar data transfer speed ... which is super slow.

Any suggestions about how I can make this fast in `GCP` ?

Comment: I can suggest apache Nifi, to read from Postgres and load it to Bigquery in a batch way.

Comment: Do you use Cloud SQL for Postgres? or a custom Postgres DB on a VM?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, Cloud SQL for Postgres.

Comment: You state: **I'd like to be able to make a full copy every 15-20 minutes**. 1) Egress traffic is charged for. Consider the costs of your strategy. 2) Transfering 100 GB every 15 minutes? What are you trying to accomplish? There are better strategies for backups and rolling recoveries. 3) If disaster recovery is not the plan, the answer from @guillaume-blaquiere is very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Cloud SQL for Postgres, the easiest way is to use [federated queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). You can create a connection in BigQuery to Cloud SQL, to query Cloud SQL directly from BigQuery.

Perform an INSERT INTO .... SELECT . And your data are copied.

*Note, you must **have a public IP on your Cloud SQL instance** (you can keep no authorized network, therefore your database is still locked and protected from the wild internet)*